# Virtual-key codes of parentheses brackets

Tags: delphi, keycode, postmessage

I am needing to PostMessage(); a pair of parentheses "( )" but I cannot seem to find their virtual-keycodes anywhere.

I've tried to ord(KeyInpunt) and it returns 40/41 yet when I try to PostMessage those values nothing happens.

I have also tried a work around of sending SHIFT + 9 / 0 without any success.

```pascal
              PostMessage(Handlea, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SHIFT, 0); // Shift
                           sleep(10);
              PostMessage(Handlea, WM_KEYDOWN, 48, 0);
                           sleep(10);
              PostMessage(Handlea, WM_KEYUP, VK_SHIFT, 0);  //Shift
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg What about it. There is nothing on that page, that explains anything to do with ( or )

Comment: @TomBrunberg MSDN's [Virtual Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) page would be a better link, since it shows the actual numeric values.

Comment: @MrClear Are you aware that [you can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513)? Use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) or [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead.  What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode` and  `KeyEvent.UnicodeChar` are:

- ( =   53  (40)
- ) =   219 (41)
- [ =   221 (91)
- ] =   186 (93)
- { =   57  (123)
- } =   48  (1235)

Answer (score 1):

These are the [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) for the `[` and `]` angled bracket keys:

```
VK_OEM_4 = 0xDB // (219) [
VK_OEM_6 = 0xDD // (221) ]
```